# Do I need to normalize corpus frequency if I am not comparing between corpora?

Tags: normalization, corpus-linguistics

Do I need to normalize my corpus frequency, given that I am not comparing corpora? For example, if I am going to compare collocations of lexicons A, B and C in a corpus with 13 million tokens, can I proceed to collocation strength testing (that is using log-likelihood test), or do I still need to normalize the frequency, for the sake of readability?